# Android Nexus5 Navigation Hiding Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, nexus-5

I'm using Nexus5 for testing application and I got issue that is Navigation bar hides **Bottom Layout**

### [image: Nexus5 Navigation Bar]

Main container is RelativeLayout which has LinearLayout on the bottom. other devices are fine and showing well but only Nexus5 has that issue because I think it has navigation bar on the bottom of screen.

Anyone has the same issue that you got? If you do, please share it.

Comment: check this link hope it will help you https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/680

Comment: Are you using any immersive mode in your app... Detail explanation about immersive mode in here :https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Comment: Post your code will help to solve the issue

Comment: thank you guys so much, I will try both of suggestions :D I'm so happy! I think I will solve that problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**// In style 21 add this line.**

```
 <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
```

for more info visit [Documentation..](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds)